# How to handle multiple keypresses at once with SDL?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, ubuntu, sdl

I need advice on keyboard event handling with SDL.

I have a 1st person camera, and can walk fwd, back, strafe left and right and use the mouse to look around which is great. Here is my processEvents function:

```
void processEvents()
{
    int mid_x = screen_width  >> 1;
int mid_y = screen_height >> 1;
int mpx = event.motion.x;
int mpy = event.motion.y;
float angle_y  = 0.0f;
float angle_z  = 0.0f;

while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    switch(event.type)
    {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case SDLK_w:
                    objCamera.Move_Camera( CAMERASPEED);
                    break;
                case SDLK_s:
                    objCamera.Move_Camera(-CAMERASPEED);
                    break;
                case SDLK_d:
                    objCamera.Strafe_Camera( CAMERASPEED);
                    break;
                case SDLK_a:
                    objCamera.Strafe_Camera(-CAMERASPEED);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
            
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            if( (mpx == mid_x) && (mpy == mid_y) ) return;

            SDL_WarpMouse(mid_x, mid_y);

            // Get the direction from the mouse cursor, set a resonable maneuvering speed
            angle_y = (float)( (mid_x - mpx) ) / 1000;      
            angle_z = (float)( (mid_y - mpy) ) / 1000;

            // The higher the value is the faster the camera looks around.
            objCamera.mView.y += angle_z * 2;

            // limit the rotation around the x-axis
            if((objCamera.mView.y - objCamera.mPos.y) > 8)  objCamera.mView.y = objCamera.mPos.y + 8;
            if((objCamera.mView.y - objCamera.mPos.y) <-8)  objCamera.mView.y = objCamera.mPos.y - 8;

            objCamera.Rotate_View(-angle_y);
            
            break;
            
        case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = true;
            break;
            
        case SDL_VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( event.resize.w, event.resize.h, screen_bpp, SDL_OPENGL | SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_RESIZABLE | SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER | SDL_HWPALETTE );
            screen_width = event.resize.w;
            screen_height = event.resize.h;
            init_opengl();
            std::cout << "Resized to width: " << event.resize.w << " height: " << event.resize.h << std::endl;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

now while this is working, it has some limitations. The biggest one and the purpose of my question is that it seems to only process the latest key that was pressed. So if I am holding 's' to walk backwards and I press 'd' to strafe right, I end up strafing right but not going backwards.

Can someone point me in the right direction for better keyboard handling with SDL, support for multiple keypresses at once, etc?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A good approach will be to write a keyboard ("input") handler that will process input events and keep the event's state in some sort of a structure (associative array sounds good - key[keyCode]).

Every time the keyboard handler receives a 'key pressed' event, it sets the key as enabled (true) and when it gets a key down event, it sets it as disabled (false).

Then you can check multiple keys at once without pulling events directly, and you will be able to re-use the keyboard across the entire frame without passing it around to subroutines.

Some fast pseudo code:

```
class KeyboardHandler {
    handleKeyboardEvent(SDL Event) {
        keyState[event.code] = event.state;
    }

    bool isPressed(keyCode) {
        return (keyState[keyCode] == PRESSED);
    }

    bool isReleased(keyCode) {
        return (keyState[keyCode] == RELEASED);
    }

    keyState[];
}

...

while(SDL Pull events)
{
    switch(event.type) {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        case SDL_KEYUP:
                keyHandler.handleKeyboardEvent(event);
            break;
        case SDL_ANOTHER_EVENT:
                ...
            break;
    }   
}

// When you need to use it:
if(keyHandler.isPressed(SOME_KEY) && keyHandler.isPressed(SOME_OTHER_KEY))
    doStuff(TM);
```

Comment: Really a nice solution,this can be used in almost all your games

Answer (score 21):

SDL keeps track of the current state of all keys.  You can access this state via:

[SDL_GetKeyState()](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GetKeyState)

So, each iteration you can update the movements based on the key state.  To make the movement smooth you should update the movement magnitude based on the time elapsed between updates.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using SDL2 then use [`SDL_GetKeyboardState`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState).

Example:

```
const Uint8 *keyboard_state_array = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

SDL_PollEvent(&event);

if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN || event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
{
    // Move centerpoint of rotation for one of the trees:
    if (keyboard_state_array[SDL_SCANCODE_UP] && !(keyboard_state_array[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN]))
    {
        --location.y;
    }
    else if (!keyboard_state_array[SDL_SCANCODE_UP] && keyboard_state_array[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN])
    {
        ++location.y;
    }

    if (keyboard_state_array[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] && !keyboard_state_array[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT])
    {
        ++location.x;
    }
    else if (!keyboard_state_array[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] && keyboard_state_array[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT])
    {
        --location.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `else ifs` and `&&s`, we can put **just** ifs and everything would be the same without the need to put extra conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of only looking at keydown events, any solution which is going to be caring about multiple keys at once is going to have to be looking at both keydown and keyup events, and keeping track of the state of the keys in question.

So instead of (pseudocode):

```
on keydown:
    case left_key:
        object.setMovement(left)
    case forward_key:
        object.setMovement(forward)
```

instead you'd have something more like (again pseudocode):

```
on keydown:
    case left_key:
        keystates[left] = true
        object.updateMovement(keystates)
    case forward_key:
        keystates[forward] = true
        object.updateMovement(keystates)

on keyup:
    case left_key:
        keystates[left] = false
        object.updateMovement(keystates)
    case forward_key:
        keystates[forward] = false
        object.updateMovement(keystates)
```

Then the `updateMovement` routine would look at `keystates` and figure out a composite movement based on the states of all movement keys together.

Answer (score 0):

use [SDL_GetKeyState](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GetKeyState) to get the keyboard state

Answer (score 0):

I know previous answers adress the issue well but I wanted to share my way which differentiate KeyUp,KeyDown and KeyHold for any key. What I do basically is just holding all keystates in two arrays called Previous and Current  so I can detect keydown, up and continues keypress all at once.

```
#include "smlkr_input_system.h"


SMLKR_InputSystem* InputSys = NULL; /*--- SINGLETON InputSys ---*/


void SMLKR_InputSystem_Init() {
     
    SMLKR_InputSystem* InputSystem = (SMLKR_InputSystem *)malloc(sizeof(SMLKR_InputSystem));
    
    InputSystem->KeyStatesPrevious = (Uint8*)calloc(512,sizeof(Uint8));
    InputSystem->KeyStatesCurrent = (Uint8*)calloc(512,sizeof(Uint8));
    InputSys = InputSystem;
}

void SMLKR_InputSystem_Feed(SDL_Event* e) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(e)) {
        if (e->type == SDL_QUIT) {
            break;
        }
    }

    memcpy(InputSys->KeyStatesPrevious,InputSys->KeyStatesCurrent,sizeof(Uint8)*512);
    memcpy(InputSys->KeyStatesCurrent,SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL),sizeof(Uint8)*512);
}

bool SMLKR_InputSystem_GetKeyDown(const SDL_Scancode keycode) {
    return InputSys->KeyStatesPrevious[keycode] == 0 && InputSys->KeyStatesCurrent[keycode] == 1;
}

bool SMLKR_InputSystem_GetKeyUp(const SDL_Scancode keycode) {
    return InputSys->KeyStatesPrevious[keycode] == 1 && InputSys->KeyStatesCurrent[keycode] == 0;
}

bool SMLKR_InputSystem_GetKey(const SDL_Scancode keycode) {
    return InputSys->KeyStatesPrevious[keycode] == 1 && InputSys->KeyStatesCurrent[keycode] == 1;
}
```

Then I use my feed function on game loop like this:

```
void SMLKR_Main_GameLoop() {

    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;

    while (!quit) {
        SDL_RenderClear(MainRenderer);
        SMLKR_InputSystem_Feed(&e);

        if(e.type==SDL_QUIT) { quit = true; }

        SMLKR_World_Update(Game->World);
        SDL_RenderPresent(MainRenderer);
    }
}
```

lastly, here is the code snippet that you can use on any .cpp to control key presses

```
if(SMLKR_InputSystem_GetKey(SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT) && SMLKR_InputSystem_GetKey(SDL_SCANCODE_UP)) {
        printf("left&up\n");
}
```

GetKeyUp and GetKeyDown also works the same way. Hope it helps!